# JavaScript 6 classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Как можно избегать префиксов "this." перед переменными в классе, если их много?
Пример:

```js
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "a";
    this.lastName = "b";
    this.age = 20;
    this.hair = "black";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запиши все проперти вначале в вспомогательный объект, а затем присвой их this.

```
class Person {
  constructor() {
    let props = {
      name : "a",
      lastName : "b",
      age : 20,
      hair : "black"
    }
    for (let prop in props) { this[prop] = props[prop]; }
  }
}
```

Но это все бред, это только сделает код тяжелее. Не бойся использовать this, или же применяй defineProperties, но от него код станет еще толще.

Так же есть экспериментальный метод Object.assing.

```
Object.assing(this, {
  name : "a",
  lastName : "b",
  age : 20,
  hair : "black"
});
```

Но насколько я знаю он поддерживается лишь Firefox, а для прочих браузеров существует лишь в виде полифила или трансплайера и по сути представляет из себя инкапсуляцию способа, что я привел вначале.

Comment: а что за `x.age`?

Comment: извеняюсь очепятка